# Pasar datos de un formulario a otro y guardar el estado

Tags: c#

Estuve horas intentando y no consigo poder pasar 2 campos de un formulario hacia otro (nombre y tiempo), para guardarlo en un listview y posteriormente guardar el estado de ese form para poder cargarlo con las puntuaciones.
Me falta la parte de guardar el estado del objeto, si no es mucho codigo me ayudaria mucho, probe con la serializacion binaria, pero pasar datos entre forms y guardarlos es algo que me cuesta todavia, dejo una foto del formulario principal y otra del secundario donde recivo los datos:

```
//Envio
            FrmTablaPuntuacion Tabla = new FrmTablaPuntuacion();

            Tabla.S_Nombre = NombreJugador;
            Tabla.S_Tiempo = lblTiempo.Text;

//Recivo
    private string Tiempo;
    private string Nombre;

    private void FrmTablaPuntuacion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem Puntuaciones = new ListViewItem(Nombre);

        Puntuaciones.SubItems.Add(Nombre);
        Puntuaciones.SubItems.Add(Tiempo);
        lvwPuntuaciones.Items.Add(Puntuaciones);

        lvwPuntuaciones.Sort();
    }

    public string S_Tiempo { set { Tiempo = value; } }
    public string S_Nombre { set { Nombre = value; } }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que no estas tratando al segundo form como un objeto (que es lo que es) y le estas pasando los parametros, pero no los estas conectando al objeto que queres mostrar.

El otro problema es que abris un nuevo form cada vez que queres mostrar los valores, en lugar de guardarlos en algun lugar (por ejemplo una clase que contenga solo eso y no sea un form), y pasarle esa clase.

```
FrmTablaPuntuacion Tabla = new FrmTablaPuntuacion();
```

Cada vez que haces eso, es un nuevo formulario. No esta guardando la vieja informacion. Es un nuevo objeto. Lo podes solucionar o usando siempre un solo form Y usando las propiedades hide and show del mismo

```
Tabla.hide();
....
Tabla.show();
```

o podrias tenes la info en una clase y pasarle esa clase cada vez que necesitas.

Lo otro que te pasa, es que le estas pasando parametros, pero vos los estas mostrando en el evento `load`.

El mismo ocurre apenas haces el new, por lo tanto, tu forma de pasarlos, aunque correcta, no los muestra.

Esto se podria solucionar con un metodo que reciba los dos, y los cargue:

```
public void RecibirDatos(String Nombre, String Tiempo)
{
    ListViewItem Puntuaciones = new ListViewItem(Nombre);
    Puntuaciones.SubItems.Add(Nombre);
    Puntuaciones.SubItems.Add(Tiempo);
    lvwPuntuaciones.Items.Add(Puntuaciones);
    lvwPuntuaciones.Sort();
}
```

y lo llamamos de la siguiente manera

```
Tabla RecibirDatos("pepe","50");
```